# Two dimensional function that belongs to $C^{1}$ but does not belong to $C^{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Give an example of a two dimensional function that belongs to $C^{1}$ but does not belong to $C^{2}$ globally. The function must have a minimum point and at that minimum point the function must be twice continuously differentiable.

In one dimension I have got one,

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}-x^3,\quad & x<1 \\  
 x^2-5x+3, \quad & x>=1 \end{cases}
$$
How to make a two-dimensional example?

Comment: Another one is $f(x)=|x|^{3/2}.$ Why not just define $F(x,y) = f(x)?$

Comment: One approach would be to modify your univariate example $f(x)$ to depend on two variables by multiplying $f(x)g(y)$ for an appropriate function $g(y)$ having a unique positive minimum.  $g(y)$ can be a smooth function, since the failure of $f(x)$ to have a continuous second derivative will carry over to the product.

Comment: @zhw:  That might be satisfactory, although the wording of the Question could indicate a unique (global) minimum point is required.

Comment: @hardmath I agree, and was just trying to coax out the precise statment of the problem from the OP in that case. (If a unique minimum is desired, then $F(x,y) = |x|^{3/2}+g(y)$ should work for a well chosen $g.$)

Comment: @zhw. Actually I need this construction for an optimization problem. I need product terms of independent variable in the function as an extra requirement.

Comment: @hardmath Actually I need this construction for an optimization problem. I need product terms of independent variable in the function as an extra requirement.

Comment: I see I had not read the last sentence of your question carefully. Why don't you try what @hardmath suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=x^2$ for $x\geqslant0$ with $g(x)=2x^2$ for $x<0$, and set $f(x,y)=g(x)+g(y)-2x-2y$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$. Then $f$ is smooth at its minimum, where $f(x,y)=-2$ at $(1,1)$, but its second derivative is undefined along the $x$ and $y$ axes.